# What to use Servers side events or Push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, windows, push-notification

We are developing step by step game and need to send a notification to all players of current game when someone made his turn. We have a REST server that uses jersey + jackson implementation.

We know that it is possible to use Google Cloud Messaging for this purpose, however it doesn't support windows phone platform (we want to support Android, iOS, Windows Phone). Yes, Microsoft has their own server, but it requires to learn API of 2 services. Also, we found that server sent events protocol exists that can help us.

Is it good idea to use SSE (on all mobile platforms) instead of push notifications or there are some better solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSE is a bad usage for your requirement, as it will only work when your app is running, no notifications will be received when your app is closed.

You should use the notification system of each plateform you target (GMC for Andorid, Apple Push Service for ios, etc.)
Each device needs to register to the notification server and then you can  send notifications to registered devices.

Since your targetting multiple plateforms, it would be easier to use a third party service that will do the registering and message dispatching to all your targetted plateforms through a simple API.

As suggested by Rahul Mathur, [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) is a known and reliable provider. Other possibilities include [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/), [PushWoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/), and a lot more !

Comment: Thanks for reply. We are decided to use parse for sending pushes to all platfroms. In the future we are going to implement long-polling for online mode (since we are using REST)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use parse as it is easy to implement
For android : https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications
For iOS : https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

You can also customise your php script on parse console.